# templatetag: QuerySet' object has no attribute 'getlist'

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm greeted with the following error when attempting to follow a books example of templatetags with modification:

```
QuerySet' object has no attribute 'getlist'report_id=88&report_id=89 HTTP/1.1" 500 180158
```

I'm following the instructions of adding templatetags to my app directory and included the **init**.py and the app_filter.py i'd like to filter on, as such:

```
Security

        accounts

           templatetags

                app_filters.py

                __init__.py
```

My app_filter.py is defined as such:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_list(querydict, itemToGet ):

    return querydict.getlist(itemToGet)
```

My settings.py includes the following:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django_python3_ldap',
    'django_extensions',
    'django_filters',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts',
]
```

My view is passing the array correctly:

```
checked = request.GET.get('report_id')
checkedlist = request.GET.getlist('report_id')


reportlist = QvReportList.objects.filter(report_id__in= checkedlist, active = 1).values_list('report_name_sc',flat = True)


print (checked)
print (checkedlist)


args = {'retreivecheckbox': reportlist}

return render(request,'accounts/requestaccess.html', args)
```

I see the array in my console, when doing a print checkedlist:

```
['75', '76', '77']
```

My template is the following:

```
{% load app_filters %}
{% for reports in retreivecheckbox %}

        {{ retreivecheckbox|get_list:'report_id' }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You've got several issues here. Your filename `app_filter.py` does not match `{% load app_filters %}`. There is also a mismatch between `Accounts` in your folder layout and `accounts` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`. What is `@register.filter('accounts/requestaccess.html')` meant to do? That's not how [`register.filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-custom-filters) works. Your filter takes an argument `itemToGet`, but you are not passing it to the filter. It should be something like `{{ retreivecheckbox|get_list:'item_to_get' }}`.

Comment: The first two were typos on my part, they are correct.  I thought @register.filter('accounts/requestaccess.html') would register the get_list filter to that template.  I believe that is my issue.

Comment: You use the filter in a templates with the `{% load %}` tag. You can use the same filter in multiple templates, it doesn't make sense to register it to a single template.

Comment: I've changed my code to just @register.filter and dropped the template.  My statement is             {{ retreivecheckbox|get_list:'report_id' }}, but now it gives me the error QuerySet' object has no attribute 'getlist'  retreievecheckboxe is the array and report_id should be the single index of that array.

Comment: It was a small syntax error.  I had to use {{ retreivecheckbox|get_list:report_id }} and not {{ retreivecheckbox|get_list:'report_id' }}

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `@register.filter` with a path. I think you mean to call it with `@register.filter('get_list')`

[Take a look at the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/): these are the two use examples:

```
@register.filter(name='cut')
def cut(value, arg):
    return value.replace(arg, '')

@register.filter
def lower(value):
    return value.lower()
```

Those would create two filters, `lower` and `cut`.

Alternatively, you can call `@register.filter` and pass the name as the first parameter, as in these cases:

```
register.filter('cut', cut)
register.filter('lower', lower)
```

Comment: changing it still gives me  'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'getlist'.  Based on Alasdair's response I removed the parameter based on the documentation:  If you leave off the name argument, as in the second example above, Django will use the function’s name as the filter name.

Finally, register.filter() also accepts three keyword arguments, is_safe, needs_autoescape, and expects_localtime. These arguments are described in filters and auto-escaping and filters and time zones below.

Comment: It was a small syntax error.  I had to use {{ retreivecheckbox|get_list:report_id }} and not {{ retreivecheckbox|get_list:'report_id' }}

Answer (score 0):

I had to use {{ retreivecheckbox|get_list:report_id }}

and not {{ retreivecheckbox|get_list:'report_id' }}

```
{% load app_filters %}
{% for reports in retreivecheckbox %}

        {{ retreivecheckbox|get_list:report_name_sc }}

    </div>
{% endfor %}
```